# Disable Alt + key shortcut keys in menu strip in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, menustrip

I am using MenuStrip in my project in vb.net. I have created two main menus: one is Master and the other is Help. Now anyone press <kbd>ALT</kbd>   +<kbd>M</kbd> then it will open master menu and if press <kbd>ALT</kbd>   +<kbd>H</kbd> then it will open Help menu.

Now I want to prevent this functionality and restrict user to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>   +<kbd>[ A KEY ]</kbd> to open menu.

Can anyone give me an idea to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your form's `KeyPreview` property to `True` and test for the key combinations you want to prevent in its `KeyDown` event, then set `e.SuppressKeyPress = True.`

However, I would generally recommend against doing this. People *expect* to be able to access menus using keyboard shortcuts in Windows applications. Denying them that option makes an application (a) non-compliant with Windows standards, and (b) less user friendly.